# Populate second node reference field based on what first node reference field is selected

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi

I have 2 content types. "ABC" content type and "DEF" content type.  In "DEF" content type i give reference to "ABC" node reference.

I am building another content type called "XYZ" where i give node reference to "ABC" and along with it i give node reference to "DEF" content type.

My problem is that i need to filter out the "DEF"(node reference to "DEF") drop down based on what "ABC" is selected from previous "ABC" drop down.

How to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to implement what you need.

One of them is to implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() to alter your content type insertion/editing form and then use [#states](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) property to alter the behavior of the drop down items.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.